# Acceder datos de una clase en otro lado (clase, controlador) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Una consulta muy tonta, tengo una clase x

```
public class classRandom
{
    public string dato1 { get; set; }
    public string dato2 { get; set; }
    public string dato3 { get; set; }
}
```

Estoy llenado sus propiedades desde un controlador usando un metodo, por que las voy utilizar despues:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void setDatos(string data1, string data2, string data3)
    {
        randomClass rC = new randomClass();
        rC.dato1=data1;
        rC.dato2=data2;
        rC.dato3=data3;
    }
```

Desde otro controlador estoy tratando de obtener los mismo valores que guarde en el controlador anterior pero me dan `null`

```
        randomClass rC = new randomClass();
        string dato1=rC.dato1;
```

A que se debe este error que no se preserva el dato?

Comment: Tiene que ver con el scope, el lugar donde instancías un objeto tiene que ver con la vida de ese objeto. Los controladores son clases que se instancían en el momento que se requieren (por ejemplo una petición) y luego se deshechan, por lo tanto, si instancías una clase dentro de un controlador, no puedes tener la certeza que los objetos creados dentro de cualquier método del controlador vayan a seguir "vivos" por el resto de vida de la aplicación. No es buena idea tener instancias globales de clases.

Comment: Creo que existe un malentendido en la forma en que accesas a la información ya que no sería posible que de un controlador acceses a otro controlador. El controlador solo se accesa una única vez y listo, termina su ciclo de vida.

Comment: Y para agregar un dato mas a todo lo que dijeron.. a quien se supone que responde ese objeto? a mi peticion? a la peticion del que venia atras mio? Por eso no hay objetos que se persistan, salvo que los mandes de un lado para otro. No hay un concepto de programa vivo aca.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes usar el `new` en otro controlador y esperar obtener lo valores magicamente, debes conservarlos en memoria, para eso existe el objeto `Session`

```
[HttpPost]
public void setDatos(string data1, string data2, string data3)
{
    randomClass rC = new randomClass();
    rC.dato1=data1;
    rC.dato2=data2;
    rC.dato3=data3;

    Session["rc"] = rC;
}
```

Y desde el otro action lo recuperas usando

```
public void OtroAction()
{
    randomClass rC = Session["rc"] as randomClass;

    if(rc == null)
    {
        //aqui controlas que no existen datos
        return;
    }

    string dato1=rC.dato1;

}
```

[Formas de almacenar datos temporales en Asp.net MVC (ViewData, ViewBag, TempData y Session)](http://tiracodigo.com/index.php/programacion/mvc/formas-de-almacenar-datos-temporales-en-asp-net-mvc-viewdata-viewbag-tempdata-y-session)

Si por alguna razon no te deja acceder a `Session` directamente puede que necesites usar `HttpContext.Current.Session`, pero no deberia pasar